# godex print in ZPL Maximum string size to 15 characters

Tags: label, zpl

I am printing labels with GODEX500 printer wiht ZPL languaje
I can't send strings longer than 15 characters!!!!
I can't print a string directly greater than 15 characters or for example in a QR code

```
printer.print "^XA
printer.print "^LH0,0
printer.print "^FT20,158^BQA,2,4
printer.print "^FDLA,MRE200020220000001/22M0 R 1 1^FS        
printer.print "^PQ1,0,1,Y
printer.print "^XZ"
```

The QR barcode only printe the string "MRE200020220000", only 15 characters

```
 printer.print "^XA
    printer.print "^LH0,0
    printer.print "^CF0,50,50
    printer.print "^FO16,16
    printer.print "^FD1^FS
    printer.print "^CF0,30,25
    printer.print "^FO340,16
    printer.print "^FDMyStringLongerthan15^FS
```

The printed string is: MyStringLongert

Do you know how I can solve this?
Thank you

Comment: How is the printer installed in windows? Have you tried Generic/Text only yet?

Comment: The printer is with the Generic/Text driver. The problem has been solved by installing the Seagull driver downloaded from the Godex website. From that moment it continues working with the Generic/Text  driver but it no longer has the problem of cutting the strings. This worries me because I can't install that driver on all computers and I don't know what the problem is